# How to create block matrix from a matrix (the block) and a number (number of repetitions) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, block

Matlab syntax question :

> Given some n x d matrix A(say [1 2 3; 4 5 6]), and a number k (say 2), how to create a block matrix in which A appears k times ( [ 1 2 3 0 0 0; 4 5 6 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 1 2 3; 0 0 0 4 5 6] in my example) ?

Another example, if A is [1 2 3; 4 5 6] and k=3 then the output should be:

```
[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0;
  4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0;
  0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0;
  0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0;
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3;
  0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6
]
```

Comment: `M = kron(eye(k),A)`

Answer (score 1):

It is quit easy, just make a loop and play with the size of the matrix `O`:

> ```
> A =[
>      1     2     3;
>      4     5     6]
> O = zeros(size(A))
> B = [A O; O A]
> B =[
>      1     2     3     0     0     0;
>      4     5     6     0     0     0;
>      0     0     0     1     2     3;
>      0     0     0     4     5     6]
> ```

I hope ur looking for this.

> ```
> clc
> A =[
>      1     2     3;
>      4     5     6]
> O = zeros(size(A))
> B = [];
> K = 3;
> line = [];
> for (i=1:K)
>     line = [];
>     for (j=1:K)
>         if (j==i)
>             line = [line A]
>         else
>             line =[line O]
>         end
>     end
>
>     B = [B; line];
> end
> ```

Comment: Yes, but how do you do that in code, given the parameter k?

Comment: can u give me an example if K=3? Cuz it is ambiguous how u would like to be matrix `B`, or a general form?

Comment: Added k=3 example in the question. Thanks.

Comment: done, hope u like it

Comment: Thanks, but Natan's comment suggests a much more elegant solution.